# Values not being updated in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor

I have a razor view for updating a model. The model is passed the the view correctly but when try the submit changes back to the controller the model is passed back unchanged.

//controller/SaveLimit

```
  public ActionResult SaveLimit(Limit _limit)
        {
            _masterData.SaveLimit(_limit);

            return RedirectToAction("MasterData");
        }
```

//view

```
@model Core.DataModel.Limit
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Calculation Master";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MasterLayout.cshtml";
}

<h2 class="centerText">Create New Employee Limit</h2>
    <div id="tabs" style="margin-left: 20px; padding-left: 20px; width: 90%;">

        <table style="margin-left: 50px; width: 35%; margin: 0 auto;">
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                <tr>
                    <td class="spin">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Limit)

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Limit)

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate)
                    </td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.ActionLink("Save", "SaveLimit", Model, new {@class = "button"})</td>
                    <td>@Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "MasterData", null, new {@class = "button"})</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>

    </div>
```

Comment: Also include the rendered HTML please, that would be valuable as well.

Comment: Also, show the full Razor code. For example, do you have an `@model` declaration at the top, and if so, show us what that is.

Comment: @JeradRose i've updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the reason it's not working is because you don't have a submit button.  A normal link won't submit the form (unless you add some JavaScript).  Add this to your view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveLimit", "yourcontroller"))
{
    // Rest of view
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to wrap all these in [Form](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) or [BeginForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform%28v=vs.108%29.aspx). Or show your background javascript if you have some.

Comment: use `<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="SubmitButton" value="Save" />` instead of `@Html.ActionLink("Save", "SaveLimit", Model, new {@class = "button"})`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the form. Wrap your form inside this:

```
using (@Html.BeginForm())
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is not working. I will update what I have above.